# Paho Mqtt Client is publishing all messages at once rather than one by one

Tags: python, mqtt, iot, paho

I am collecting telemetry data from my sensor node to my raspberry pi through mqtt.There are 2 MQTT clients conected to a broker on localhost and broker on my VPS. The pi collects the data from the sensor node and sends it to my VPS server.

If the pi goes offline it will collect all the values in a local database and then, after reconnection, its supposed to send the messages one by one to the VPS.

Normally the messages are getting published one by one. But when it disconnects & then reconnects it creates a thread "redundancywork()" and by the code it is supposed to publish messages one by one.

But this is what ends up happening:

```
2018-02-28 00:29:00.304932,4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0
2018-02-28 00:29:01.074249,4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0
2018-02-28 00:29:01.496664,4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0
2018-02-28 00:29:01.912588,4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0
2018-02-28 00:29:02.264558,4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0
Message Published
Message Published
Message Published
Message Published
Message Published
```

It prints out the rows but publishes only AFTER the loop ends even though the publish function is within the loop. And after that it publishes normally one by one. The message does not get queued during disconnection as I set it that way. This is my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from model import SN1, Base
from datetime import datetime
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import threading
import time
import os


#Topics to Subscribe to as (Topic Name, QOS Level)
topics = [("SN1",2)]
broker = "localhost"
portno = 1883


#Disconnect CHecker
DISCONNECT = "NO"


##Redundancy Stuff
redundancydb_url = 'sqlite:///redundancy.db'
redunandcy_engine = create_engine(redundancydb_url)
Base.metadata.bind = redunandcy_engine
if os.path.isfile("redundancy.db") is False:
    Base.metadata.create_all(redunandcy_engine)
redunandcysession = sessionmaker(bind = redunandcy_engine)
redundancydb = redunandcysession()


'''
Helper Methods
'''

#ToSubscribe
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    global DISCONNECT
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe(topics)

    #CHECK IF VPS CLIENT
    if client._client_id == "VPS Client" and DISCONNECT == "YES":
        DISCONNECT = "NO"
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Redundancy Work Begins")
        thread = threading.Thread(target = redundancywork())
        thread.start()

#Message Processing
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    decoded = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
    nowtime = datetime.now()
    message = decoded.split(",")
    print(message[0])
    global DISCONNECT
    global vpsclient


    #MESSAGE SENDING
    if message[0] == "SN1":
        if DISCONNECT == "NO":
            message_payload = "{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(nowtime, message[1], message[2], message[3], message[4], message[5])
            print(message_payload)
            vpsclient.publish("SN1", payload = message_payload, qos = 1)
        if DISCONNECT == "YES":
            newvalues = SN1(nowtime, message[1], message[2], message[3], message[4], message[5])
            redundancydb.add(newvalues)
            redundancydb.commit()
            print("Inserted to Redundancy DB")

def on_publish(client, userdata,mid):
    print("Message Published")

#Disconnection Handler
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("Client {} has disconnected From Broker".format(client._client_id))
    global DISCONNECT
    DISCONNECT = "YES"

def redundancywork():
    #Get First Value of DB
    global vpsclient

    rdbsession = sessionmaker(bind = redunandcy_engine)
    rdb = rdbsession()
    first = rdb.query(SN1).first()
    print(first)

    #Check if length of firstrow is not 0
    while first is not None:
        message_payload = "{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(first.date, first.airtemp, first.humidity, first.watertemp, first.light, first.ph)
        print(message_payload)
        vpsclient.publish("SN1", payload = message_payload, qos = 1)
        #DELETE ROW
        rdb.delete(first)
        rdb.commit()

        #FETCH ROW
        first = rdb.query(SN1).first()
        time.sleep(2)

'''
Main Function
'''


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #Local Broker Client
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client._client_id = "Local Client"
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.on_publish = on_publish
    client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
    client.connect(broker, portno, keepalive = 20)

    #Vps Broker Client
    vpsbroker = "*"
    vpsportno = 1883
    global vpsclient
    vpsclient = mqtt.Client()
    vpsclient._client_id = "VPS Client"
    vpsclient.on_connect = on_connect
    vpsclient.on_publish = on_publish
    vpsclient.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
    vpsclient.max_inflight_messages_set(20)
    vpsclient.connect(vpsbroker, vpsportno, keepalive = 20)


while True:
    try:
        client.loop_start()
        vpsclient.loop_start()
    except Exception:
        continue
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't just take 2 seconds for the four packets to be sent back and forth for QoS level 2? What happens when you queue up 100 rows instead of just 5?

Comment: Let me try queueing up many rows.

Comment: I queued up about 50 rows. It was the exact same result. The 50 rows was printed and then the message got published only after the loop ended. I checked it on my server side and the messages were getting printed only after the loop ended.

Comment: @Blender I tried QOS 0 also. Its sending messages only after the loop ends.

Comment: Try replacing `threading.Thread(target = redundancywork())` with `threading.Thread(target = redundancywork)`. You're calling `redundancywork` in the main thread, not in a separate thread.

Comment: @Blender Thanks! That fixed it!